# Can this be done in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a web app using codeigniter. Now if I want to load variables from one function to another function when the function is called, then is it possible? Consider an example below:

Supppose there are two functions inside a same class as follows:

```
Class Form extends CI_Controller(){

function submit()
{
 $data['title'] = "Website";
 $data['header'] = "Welcome to my website";
 $this->load->vars($data);
 $this->load->view('welcome');
}

function xyz()
{
 $data['footer'] ="Mywebsite 2011 Copyright";
 $this->submit();
}
}
```

Is it possible that when I call xyz function, the $data['footer'] is included in the submit() function? Like submit() loads $data['footer'] into $this->loads->vars($data)?  If not what can be done to include the same?

Comment: you can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. The first one is to pass the data as a parameter, for instance:

```
Class Form extends CI_Controller(){

function submit($footer = false)
{
  $data['footer'] = $footer; // set the footer. 
 $data['title'] = "Website";
 $data['header'] = "Welcome to my website";
 $this->load->vars($data);
 $this->load->view('welcome');
}

function xyz()
{
 $data['footer'] ="Mywebsite 2011 Copyright";
 $this->submit($data['footer']);
}
}
```

The alternative is to set the footer data as a class variable, which would be available to all functions in the controller, like this:

```
Class Form extends CI_Controller(){

var $footer = false; 

function submit()
{
  $data['footer'] = $this->footer; // get the footer. 
 $data['title'] = "Website";
 $data['header'] = "Welcome to my website";
 $this->load->vars($data);
 $this->load->view('welcome');
}

function xyz()
{
 $this->footer = "Mywebsite 2011 Copyright";
 $this->submit($data['footer']);
}
}
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/user.php

Line Number: 21
 It gives this

Comment: The error got resolved. Now I want to expand my question, and would like to ask you that if I call the submit function from a form such as {form_open(form/submit)} what can be done to pass the value of footer through form ?

Comment: Well all you need is to add a hidden field lets say "footer" and provide a value for the same. Then you need to fetch that data using the code below: **`$data['footer'] = $this->input->post('footer');`** inside the submit function.